# Why would Luke Skywalker and Lars live in an igloo on a planet with two suns?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, a-new-hope

If you look at Uncle Owen's home on Tatooine, it was igloo-shaped with no windows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Real igloos are designed to trap hot air inside (which is useful in a harshly cold environment) and I want to know why Lucas wanted to show this on a hot planet. Note that this home was unique in design on Tatooine.

Also, in-universe, whether the walls were heat conductor or insulator, green house effect would kick in without air flow (no windows.) Also, they used to shut down power at night, meaning, you are going to boil even if you've best-in-class air conditioner. Where's the catch? Anything even from legends?

Comment: [Due to it being partially submerged, it's actually really efficient at keeping cool.](http://www.treehugger.com/slideshows/green-architecture/more-hobbit-houses-earth-sheltered-houses-are-great-green-way-live/page/4/#slide-top) This isn't really a SFF question.

Comment: Actually they lived underground. The igloo is just the entrance. Living underground in the desert is useful because the ground moderates the extreme temperatures of day and night.

Comment: For funsies, it's worth noting that the "igloo" was only complete from the front; https://artselectronic.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/star-wars-tunisa-1.jpg

Comment: Thick stone walls are common in a lot of hot/desert areas (which canhave very cold nights) on Earth - it actually acts as a thermal insulator, keeping the interior cool during the day and warmer during the night.

Comment: Wow man, did we really need the spoilers in the title? ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "igloo" isn't actually their home. It is, in fact the entrance to their home, most of which is buried in order to protect it from the grinding heat of the Tatooine day.

The [Star Wars: Complete Locations](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Complete_Locations) factbook identifies this as the "Entry Dome" to their homestead

[image]

Along with providing a much larger cutaway of the underground areas

[image]

The [Star Wars: Visual Guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20080209114108/http://www.starwars.com/episode-iv/explore/visualguides/chp08.html) (alas now defunct, but referenced in multiple locations) stated that the dome...

> ...was made from pourstone, and hand-built by Cliegg Lars. It featured
>   an external security access keypad and message center, and was
>   commonly surrounded by various apparatus such as dew condenser jugs
>   and area sensors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an igloo, it's a dome it's not the main house it's the entrance to the house sunk underground. Earth sheltering is a building technique of using the thermal properties of the underground to use the layers of ground as insulation against the suns heat. Visit Monaco, Istanbul, Rome and Barcelona if you want examples of excellent architecture in hot/dry climates. What did they do?

1: High and Narrow: They built high without scraping the sky and built narrow without causing claustrophobia. Buildings are typically 3-5 stories but never more than 10 (in ancient history what was possible for the engineering technology of the time) and the streets were narrow. Thus buildings taller than the width of the adjacent street provided shade. Many buildings of public had colonnades or awnings, something that provided shade as well.

2: Topography: Before the advent of the bulldozer and backhoe, building flat was never much for most societies less they were building whole cities. Like San Francisco’s hilly houses many desert cities have buildings that rise and fall with the terrain. Because a building on a hill with awnings is a shade lovers paradise.

3: Interior height: When realtors advertise 9-10 foot ceiling they’re scamming you. Increase in ceiling height increase the useless air volume you have to heat and cool. Before HVAC, high ceilings where the chimney effect to dispose of air heat. Today’s plywood mcmansions are sealed tighter so they don’t breathe they heat up. It takes 19 BTU’s of energy to raise the temp of 1000 cubic feet of air one degree Fahrenheit. It take 2-3 times that to lower it (Air conditioning).
Every inch in ceiling reduction per 1000 sq ft reduces volume by 83 cubic feet

4: Love (and avoid) that Sun! Man: Despite thousands of years of technological progression in building, there’s no substitute for the southern facing house and the thermal mass wall. Passive solar design doesn’t involve new technology…which is why engineers in the Silicon age hate it. Orientation and shape, as well as the appropriate building materials. This resulted in many vernacular building styles in different parts of the world. In contrast, most modern buildings look the same wherever they stand.

5: Think Fortress: Lot of desert and hot climate architecture in the ancient world by virtue of engineering technology of the day resembled fortresses…..But they served their purpose. THICK walls, some nearly a foot or more offered many perks, not just protection from cannon balls. The suns thermal energy requires almost 12 hours to be conducted through a wall 35 cm (14 in) thick. Narrow windows and louvers armored against the sun.

6: Respect the Rock. Other than mud, Stone is humanity’s oldest building material. Two longest lasting building materials, Stone and ceramic. Regardless of environment; ages gracefully. While stone is expensive, it truly isn’t. It’s expensive to transport. But Hot places are not devoid of rock, it’s ubiquitous and using local materials in building construction usually entices the thrifty.

7: Courtyard: air, light, privacy, security, and tranquility. Without the maintenance prone upkeep of the front and backyard

[image: Luke looking down into house courtyard]